# Using Google Sites and Google App Scripts, how can I dynamically change the CSS class of an HTML element?

Tags: css, google-sites

I am using Google Sites for my webpage and I want parts of it to be kind of dynamic. Hence, what I want to achieve is to change the CSS class associated with certain HTML element in the presence of an on click event.

E.g.: 
Initial situation:

```
<div class="foo">Hello</div>
<a href="#" onlick="method()">World</a>
```

After clicking on "World":

```
<div class="bar">Hello</div>
<a href="#" onlick="method()">World</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an ID to the div, then:

```
function method() {
  var myDiv = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  myDiv.className = "bar";
}
```

Alternatively you can get all elements with that particular class name, then loop through them to change their class name.

```
function method() {
  var myDivs = document.getElementsByClassName("foo");

for (var i = 0; i < myDivs.length; i++)
    myDivs[i].className = "bar";
}
```

Now of course you can add if/else statements to check for certain conditions before making changes.

Comment: Unfortunately, `documet. ...` does not work in Google App Scripts.

Comment: Are you using the HTML service to create your page from the GAS doGet() function?

Comment: Ah I see, I think you're trying to change your actual Google site from GAS, is that correct? What I've been doing is creating GAS web apps, using HTML service to create custom HTML forms and such that I can embed into the site, and completely manipulate it from there. I'm not sure how much control you have over directly manipulating your Google site page elements.

Comment: As of now I was not using GAS. I created my sites using Google Sites only. So I know that there is the possibility to include App Scripts into the sites, but I do not quite understand how I can make your code work with the existing sites.

Comment: Thank you. I solved the problem by creating the site using GAS. Where you then able to avoid the `This application was created by another user, not by Google.` message?

Comment: I don't remember getting that msg. Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107339/discussion-between-florian-and-gerneio).

Answer (score 0):

Now that I understand what you are looking for, Check this [link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/sites/page).

There is a get and set method for the HTML content of the page requested. By manipulating the generated string, it should be possible to then change the div to the required class and other such things. This should be a good start, we'll have to play around with the rest.

[This](https://support.google.com/sites/answer/2500646?hl=en) might also be helpful, but I believe it has several limitations.